# How can i enter User information in the Data element of a list instance

Tags: caml-query, list-definition

For example...

```
<Rows>
  <Row>
    <Field Name="ClassName">Programming 101</Field>
    <Field Name="Attendee">Domain\User</Field>
  </Row>
 </Rows>
```

Does not work...

Comment: Error message ? I suspect it won't works as the value requires to be in the format `1;#Domain\User`. That means you have to know the ID in advance, and thus, probably a custom feature receiver will be required (or EventReceiver with listadded event, depending on your needs)

Comment: @SteveB: I'd recommend adding that as an answer